# What is the correct annotation so I can get Autowired EntityManagerFactory?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to get an autowired EntityManagerFactory in a class which is being used in my Spring boot application.  I think the problem is stemming from the fact that my class is in a separate package.

I generated a simple sample case to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Here is the application class:

```
package test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import test2.GetEMF;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AutoWiredTest implements CommandLineRunner {
  @Autowired
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) 
  throws Exception {
    if( emf == null )
      System.out.println("Top: EMF is null");
    else
      System.out.println("Top: Got EMF instance");      
    new GetEMF();
 }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(AutoWiredTest.class, args);
  }
}
```

Here is the GetEMF class in a different package:

```
package test2;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@PersistenceContext
public class GetEMF {
  @Autowired
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;
  
  public GetEMF() {
    if( emf == null )
      System.out.println("Inner: EMF is null");
    else
      System.out.println("Inner: Got EMF instance");      
  }
}
```

When I run the code, I get this output:

```
Top: Got EMF instance
Inner: EMF is null
```

From reading online, I thought the @PersistenceContext annotation would fill in the emf, but it is no.

I know it looks like I can simply pass a reference for the emf to the GetEMF constructor, but that is a quirk of the simple test case. It won't work for my application.  I have to get an EntityManagerFactory from the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `emf` field in `GetEMF` is `null` because you have created the instance yourself:

```
new GetEMF();
```

If you want Spring to inject dependencies, for example into `@Autowired` fields, then the instance needs to be a bean managed by Spring.

You could annotate `GetEMF` with `@Component` and then autowire it into `AutoWiredTest`.

Comment: The problem is that I am using reflection to instantiate my classes so I can't get them by autowired

Comment: Then you should update your question or ask a new one as it doesn’t describe the problem that you are trying to solve

Comment: OK, I get that.  I figured out I should be using a CRUDRepository instead of this approach so this is the wrong approach anyway.  Thank you!